# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near FROM

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm having a problem with this piece of PHP. It's meant to print out a table of products chosen from the last page - passed through POST with names in the format 'quantityN' where N is a number <150 & refers to a unique ID - primary key - in the table CSGames.

I know that the problem isn't with my $connection, as I successfully load the list in the last page.

The error:

```
Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM" LINE 1: ...efnumber,name,platform,price WHERE refnumber='20' FROM CSGam... ^ in /berw/homes1/g/gij2/public_html/cs25010/basket.php on line 102
```

My live project can be found [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/gij2/cs25010/) - index>catalogue>basket.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

```
echo "
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Title
            </td>
            <td>
                Platform
            </td>
            <td>                                            
                Price
            </td>
            <td>
                Quantity
            </td>
            <td>
                Total price
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ";

$id=0;
$sum=0;
while($id<150){ //  Loops through the POST associative array
    if($_POST['quantity'.$id]>0){
        $result=pg_fetch_row(pg_query($connection,"SELECT refnumber,name,platform,price WHERE refnumber='".$id."' FROM CSGames"));
        $total=$result[4]*$_POST['quantity'.$id];
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ".$result[1]."
                </td>
                <td>
                    ".$result[2]."
                </td>
                <td>
                    &pound;".$result[3]."
                </td>
                <td>
                    ".$_POST['quantity'.$id]."
                </td>
                <td>
                    &pound;".$total."
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
        $sum+=$total;
    }
    $id++;
}
```

Comment: The syntax is `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE criteria` - you've got FROM and WHERE the wrong way round.

Comment: `FROM` always precedes `WHERE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT refnumber, name, platform, price FROM CSGames WHERE refnumber='".$id."'
```

should work. SELECT statements are always structured like so:

```
SELECT [column names] FROM [table name] WHERE [conditions]
```

Your query was structured like:

```
SELECT [column names] WHERE [conditions] FROM [table name]
```

Comment: I must have tried pretty much every order except that, thanks.

Comment: @Psygnosys: If in doubt, the fine, trusty manual will help: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html